# Access group_vars/all in dynamic inventory script

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My inventory directory structure looks like this

```
./group_vars
./group_vars/all
./inventory
./inventory.py
```

I have static inventory and dynamic inventory script, and group_vars/all has some variables that I would like to access inside inventory.py, is there a way to achieve this, or any information on how a structure like this gets parsed by ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `inventory.py` and use [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to load the group_vars/all.yml
Example code:

```
import yaml
document = """
  a: 1
  b:
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
print yaml.dump(yaml.load(document))
```

Comment: Good idea, what about embedded vars? I.e. v1: "{{v2}}/some", I guess I could try parsing jinja2 library

Comment: @srs it's been almost 3 years now. Hope you have found your answer. if not, [here is one way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465952/1318643)