# Using inventory group variables in dynamic inventory script

Tags: python, ansible

This question is exactly like this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549965/access-group-vars-all-in-dynamic-inventory-script). And I am hoping I get some different answer with this one. I have been trying to achieve this for over a year. but can't seem to achieve it.

Stripped down version of my ansible directory looks like this:

```
[root@python-test ansible]# tree
.
├── files
├── inventory
│   ├── prod
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all
│   │   └── hosts -> ../../scripts/inventory.py
│   └── staging
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all
│       └── hosts -> ../../scripts/inventory.py
├── roles
│   ├── ant
│   ├── build
│   ├── jdk
│   └── python
├── scripts
│   └── inventory.py
├── templates
└── vars
    └── all.yaml
```

I would like to use some of the variables declared in `group_vars/all` file. It has some endpoint details that I can use during the script execution. A striped down version of this `group_vars/all` looks like this:

```
inv_cloudprovider: aws
inv_environment: prod
inv_environment_type: production
inv_vpc_cidr: 10.0.0.0/16
inv_build_url: 'https://build.{{inv_environment}}.local'
inv_cloud_vpc_name: '{{inv_environment}}-vpc'
inv_vpc_id: '{{inv_environment_type}}-{{inv_cloud_vpc_name}}'
inv_glassfish_version: 4
```

At this point I am loading this file using yaml.safe_loads() and then using them in script execution. but problem with that is there are variables which are recursive jinja templates. and I am having hard time getting to make those variables work. So I was wondering if I can use ansible to do this for me.

I am using `ansible==2.2.3.0` and `python 2.7`.

The closest I have been to achieving this in python by doing this:

```
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory

inventory_path = '/root/ansible/inventory/prod/hosts'
inventory = Inventory(DataLoader(), VariableManager(), inventory_path)
group = inventory.get_group('all')
group_vars = group.get_vars()
```

Which is probably not the correct way because my script tries to execute itself and that goes on recursively.

Is it possible to parse group vars variable using ansible? If no, how do I best get final value of variables from that file?

Comment: `I am using ansible==2.2.3.0` <= before anything else it's about time to upgrade to a version >= 2.9. Once this is done, you should consider migrating your inventory script to an [inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-dynamic-inventory) that can most probably handle your current problem out of the box.

Comment: @Zeitounator   Yes. Ansible upgrade work is also in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stripped down version of code that can do what this question asked is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import os
import sys
import yaml
from jinja2 import Environment

class VarLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    @staticmethod
    def construct_python_string(text):
        return str(text.value)

    def yaml_remove_parse(self, text):
        self.construct_python_string(text)

env_name = os.environ.get('ENV_NAME')
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ansible_dir_path = os.path.abspath(script_path + '/../')
global_vars_path = ansible_dir_path + '/vars/all.yaml'
inventory_vars_path = ansible_dir_path + '/inventory/' + env_name + '/group_vars/all'

with open(global_vars_path) as f1, open(inventory_vars_path) as f2:
    global_vars_data = f1.read()
    inventory_vars_data = f2.read()

all_vars_data = global_vars_data + '\n' + inventory_vars_data
VarLoader.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:float', VarLoader.yaml_remove_parse)
data = yaml.load(all_vars_data, Loader=VarLoader)
jinja_env = Environment()
template_file = jinja_env.from_string(all_vars_data)

for key in data:
    val = data[key]
    if isinstance(val, str) and '{{' in val:
        template = jinja_env.from_string(val)
        data[key] = template.render(**data)

yaml_data = yaml.load(template_file.render(data), Loader=VarLoader)
print(json.dumps(yaml_data))
```

This works with both python3 and python2. Output:

```
[root@python-test ansible]# python scripts/inventory.py | jq .
{
  "inv_environment": "prod",
  "inv_environment_type": "production",
  "inv_cloudprovider": "aws",
  "gv_redis_port": 6379,
  "inv_glassfish_version": 4,
  "inv_vpc_id": "production-prod-vpc",
  "gv_redis_version": "4.0.11",
  "inv_build_url": "https://build.prod.local",
  "gv_glassfish_admin_user": "admin",
  "inv_vpc_cidr": "10.0.0.0/16",
  "gv_glassfish_asadmin_path": "/usr/local/glassfish/bin/asadmin",
  "gv_java_home": "/usr/local/java/default",
  "inv_cloud_vpc_name": "prod-vpc",
  "gv_tomcat_home": "/usr/local/tomcat",
  "gv_java_path": "/usr/local/java/default/bin/java"
}
```